# Nodejs check gender by name

Tags: node.js

I need to check gender by name. I have list of name in first form, such as: "Peter", "Anna" and etc. Its not very complicated, but application must return probability of gender,than name is not in first form, example "Peter" and "Petka" is equal. Maybe somebody knows good solution for NodeJS?

Comment: If you try to create some software to guess a persons sex based on their name you're likely to end up offending a lot of people when it inevitably doesn't work

Comment: @andrew Our marketing application must understand gender of our costumer by GET param "name". It's my task and i try to complete it.

Comment: you'll need a huge data base of names and genders, even then it won't work for names like 'sam'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely to fail quite often, and as pointed in comments, it may even offend some. That being said, there is an api that does exactly that : [Genderize.io](http://genderize.io/)

It returns results like : `{"name":"peter","gender":"male","probability":"0.99","count":796}` You can also localize your query for more accuracy.

And their db is 177k names large, so it's probably your best bet.

EDIT :

To take the example you mention, here's what it returns for 'Petka' :

```
{
  name: "petka",
  gender: "female",
  probability: "1.00",
  count: 2
}
```

So I guess there's room for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use [name2gender.com](https://name2gender.com) with free 10000 api calls per month

response for 'peter':

```
{
  "name" : "peter",
  "gender" : "MALE",
  "accuracy" : 98.53,
  "samples" : 253705,
  "country" : "WORLD",
  "durationMs" : 0
}
```

more samples means more result of precision

Answer (score 0):

You could also use https://veriocheck.com

They have API for name to gender lookup but they also provide name corrections along with it which we find more useful. So if the name was misspelled or incorrect, they provide corrections and then lookup correct gender.

Answer (score 0):

you can check https://genderapi.io

> https://genderapi.io/api?name=peter;anna

```json
{
  "status": true,
  "duration": "56ms",
  "used_credits": 2,
  "q": "peter;anna",
  "names": [
    {
      "name": "peter",
      "q": "peter",
      "gender": "male",
      "total_names": 4787,
      "probability": 100
    },
    {
      "name": "anna",
      "q": "anna",
      "gender": "female",
      "total_names": 9609,
      "probability": 100
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a professional API service like [parser.name](https://parser.name/) for this. You can post a name like [Peter](https://parser.name/example/peter/) or [Anna](https://parser.name/example/anna/) and you'll get back the gender of the names within milliseconds.

```
firstname: {
    name: "Anna",
    name_ascii: "Anna",
    validated: true,
    gender: "f",
    gender_formatted: "female",
    unisex: false,
    gender_deviation: 0,
    country_code: "US",
    country_certainty: 31,
    country_rank: 28,
    alternative_countries: {
        GB: 13,
        PL: 8,
        SE: 6
    }
}
```